OData query for analyzedEmails endpoint Graph API invalid filter?
I've been messing around with the new analyzedEmails endpoint, but it being in the Beta version of the Graph API, it obviously lacks in some functionality. Nonetheless, this is the one endpoint that I can't make a simple odata filter.
This works:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/collaboration/analyzedEmails?startTime=2024-08-16&endTime=2024-08-20&filter=networkMessageId eq 'c457572a-10c5-4f39-e04c-0g4cc06e2ff3'

This does NOT work:
Error: 400 (Invalid filter clause)
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/collaboration/analyzedEmails?startTime=2024-08-16&endTime=2024-08-20&filter=networkMessageId eq 'c457572a-10c5-4f39-e04c-0g4cc06e2ff3' or networkMessageId eq 'd4453054-64bf-4f22-b84e-08ddd072fe6a'

It is extremely frustrating that I cannot filter for two or more networkMessageIds. Sure, I can develop some work around.
Am I doing anything wrong here?
I tried all sorts of other filter query parameters, but again, it seems constrained to whatever the official documentation page showcases.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-collaborationroot-list-analyzedemails?view=graph-rest-beta

perhaps it supports in, hard to tell (the api is poorly documented). networkMessageId in ('c457572a-10c5-4f39-e04c-0g4cc06e2ff3', 'd4453054-64bf-4f22-b84e-08ddd072fe6a')

Your query with or is correct, but if it fails, it means that is not supported by the endpoint itself.
